# Can we create a abstract class without using abstract keyword?

Tags: oop, c#-4.0

This question is asked by an interviewer in one of my interviews.

we can avoid creating  instance of the class by using private constructor then we cannot inherit that class

Comment: Private constructors are used in Singleton implementations which are anything but abstract

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the private constructor, but that does not make your class abstract.

It just means that other classes cannot create a new instance of your class.

But your class can still call its own constructor through a static method, therefore creating a new instance of itself.

If you don't want a class to be instanciated at all, never ever, use the Abstract keyword...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an object only in the "inheritance-hierachy" you need the protected-keyword (see also for access modifiers in general https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

If you want to have an abstract behaviour, whats the reason for not take abstract keyword?

Comment: The only meanigful reason for a private class, btw, I consider you´ll find here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffa250ea-cb88-4a17-a1fe-876997dfa96f/private-class-in-c?forum=csharplanguage
But in most cases I would take either public class, with private members/methods, or abstract class, as a "mother-class"... Hope that helps

Comment: I don't need that behaviour .its a question asked my interviewer .I want to know whether  can create abstract class without using abstract keyword